# Change color of a shape according color input type javesctipt

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have used a colorPicker and want to take the value and set it.

I have used this:

```
 <li id="color"><input type="color" name="color" onchange="changeColor()"></li>

function changeColor(){
    var selectedShapes = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    var len = selectedShapes.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        selectedShapes[i].style.background = document.getElementsByName("color");
    }
}
```

This is the file:
http://jsbin.com/mebiriruzi/edit?css,js,output

how do I use the color input of the user?

Comment: To set the color, first get the selected color value using `document.getElementsByName("color")[0].value`. [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/vopisipeye/1/edit?css,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("color")` return a list of elements as suggested by the "s" in getElementsByName. You could use an id and then do `document.getElementById("color").value` or select the first occurance of "color" if you only have one with `document.getElementsByName("color")[0].value`

So you can either do:

```
function changeColor(){
    var selectedShapes = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    var len = selectedShapes.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        selectedShapes[i].style.background = document.getElementsByName("color")[0].value;
    }
}
```

or

```
<li id="color"><input type="color" id="mySelectedColor" name="color" onchange="changeColor()"></li>
```

And then in js:

```
function changeColor(){
    var selectedShapes = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    var len = selectedShapes.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        selectedShapes[i].style.background = document.getElementById("mySelectedColor").value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByName` method returns an array containing all of the elements that matched the name. Even when there is only one element matching the name, an array will still be returned, so to get the first item from this array, you should include bracket notation to address element 0 (the first). As this will return a DOM node, you will need to get the `value` property of the returned element:

```
document.getElementsByName("color")[0].value
```